# Need helping on htaccess redirect

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mobile, http-redirect

How can I achieve this in HTACCESS. What I want is that if a user is using a Smartphone device and access the link `http://luxury.localhost/others/mypage.html` he will be redirected to `http://luxury.localhost/sp/entry` but if he is just using a PC he will be redirected to `http://luxury.localhost/entry` page.

Code:

```
# the logic is something like this
# If using smartphone
RedirectMatch /others/mypage.html /sp/entry/

# else if using PC
RedirectMatch /others/mypage.html /entry/
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12693388/redirect-for-mobile-device-with-htaccess-exclude-ipad

Comment: Try this in your HTACCESS to redirect mobile users:  ########## Begin - Redirect Mobile Browser Accessing /siteurltoredirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^siteurltoredirect$ http://luxury.localhost/sp/entry [R,L]
########## End - Redirect Mobile Browser Accessing /siteurltoredirect